# Rewriting 2D stationary heat equation.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, heat-equation

I'm given the following stationary heat equation in 2D:

$$\nabla\cdot q=f, \quad q=-k\nabla u, \tag1$$

where $u$ is the temperature, $q$ is the heat flow, $k$ is the conduction coefficient and $f$ a given production term.

Normally, the heat equation in 2D is given as

$$u_t = -k(u_{xx} + u_{yy}), \tag2$$

but how do I go from (1) to (2)? My first thought was that i can multiply (1) with $\nabla$ and then get

$$\nabla\cdot q=-k\nabla^2u \implies f=-k\nabla^2u=-k(u_{xx}+u_{yy}).$$

Is $f=u_t$ then? If $q$ is the heat flow, then $f=\nabla\cdot q$ is the change in heat flow, and not the change in temperature $u_t$ as I want it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really missing anything.

You are given a *specific stationary* differential equation.

Since it represents a heat equation, we can conclude that $u_t=f$, where $f$ would be independent of $t$ since the heat distribution is supposed to be stationary.

That is, you're supposed to match the given equation to the heat equation and draw conclusions.